# how can i insert database record when a button is clicked - Codeigniter, jquery, ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

so here is my problem, i am creating my own upvote and downvote feature in my school project. All i want to happen is when I click an arrow-up image, it will insert a record to database. It will add a one record to upvote table in my database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {



   $("#try").click(function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var thread_id = $("#thread_id").val();
        var vote = $("#vote").val();

        $.ajax(
            {
                type:"post",
                url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/Users/add_vote/",
                data:{ username:username, thread_id:thread_id, vote:vote},
                success:function(data)
                {
                   alert("POST SUBMITTED");

                }


            });



});
   });
```

and here is my form

```
<div id = "active_upvote_div">
                <form>
                    <input type="hidden" name = "username" id="username" value= "try">
                    <input type="hidden" name="thread_id" id="thread_id" value= "1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="vote" id="vote" value= "1">
                <button type="submit" id="try"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/public/images/upvote.png"   height:"25px" width="25px"/> </button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

My Controller only calls the model

This is my Model

```
 public function ajax()
      {
         $add_user = array(
        'username'     => $this->input->post('username'),
        'thread_id' => $this->input->post('thread_id'),
        'vote' => $this->input->post('vote'),

             );

       $this->db->insert('thread_upvote', $add_user);
      }
```

hoping for an immediate response :(

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter `$this->input->post()` is equivalent to `$_POST` which makes array of posted names as `key/value` pair.

In your `controller's add_vote()` function do this...

```
public function add_vote()
{
$data = $this->input->post();
$this->load->model('model_namel');//loads model
$this->model_name->ajax($data);//call model's function with data
}
```

Then in `model's ajax()` function

```
public function ajax($data=array())
{
   $this->db->insert('thread_upvote', $data);// inserts into database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   $("#active_upvote_div").click(function(){
       var username = $("#username").val();
       var thread_id = $("#thread_id").val();
       var vote = $("#vote").val();

       $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           dataType: 'json', //add this to call json
           url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/Users/add_vote/",
           data:{ username:username, thread_id:thread_id, vote:vote},
           success:function(data)
           {
               if(data.success == true){
                    alert("POST SUBMITTED");
               } else{
                    alert("Failed to Post");
               }
           }
       });
   });
});
```

In your Controller:

```
Class Users extends CI_Controller{
   public function add_vote()
   {
       $result = $this->name_of_model->ajax(); //call the ajax function in you model
       echo json_encode($result); //check the return if true or false and pass to json
   }
}
```

In your Model:

```
public function ajax()
{
   $add_user = array(
      'username'     => $this->input->post('username'),
      'thread_id' => $this->input->post('thread_id'),
      'vote' => $this->input->post('vote'),
   );

   if($this->db->insert('thread_upvote', $add_user))
   {
       return true;
   } else{
       return false;
   }
}
```